# Tener "cuentas pendientes"

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, definiciones

Otra vez estaba escribiendo y me interesa saber cómo expresar **en inglés** el hecho de que algo es una "cuenta pendiente" (que es bien distinto de que dos personas tengan "cuentas pendientes" o que no haya pagado la luz y la "cuenta esté pendiente").

Por ejemplo:

> Mi formación es buena en historia medieval pero el período previo siempre ha sido una "cuenta pendiente".

Es probable que haya varias opciones con distinta connotación. Estoy interesado en todas ellas (aunque personalmente pienso que cuenta pendiente no tiene por qué ser siempre negativa, puede reflejar que es algo que no pudo hacerse a pesar del interés en ello).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La expresión que buscas es **unfinished business**.

> Those two have unfinished business.

o en tu ejemplo

> .... but the previous period has always been an *unfinished business* for me

Comprueba [este enlace](http://diccionario.reverso.net/ingles-espanol/we%20have%20unfinished%20business)

Answer (score 4):

Mi sugerencia es usar una expresión bastante similar, que es tener una `asignatura pendiente`.

A diferencia de `cuenta pendiente` no tiene la connotación de "deuda". Como bien dices `cuenta pendiente` suele usarse en contextos de "deber algo a alguien", ya sea a la compañía del gas o a otra persona por distintas razones (incluso de "revancha" o "venganza").

> Batman tiene una *cuenta pendiente* con el Joker desde que le pintó el batmóvil de rosa.
>
> Fulano tiene una cuenta pendiente con ese tipo porque le robó la novia.

La expresión `asignatura pendiente` por el contrario es más una "cosa que **a mi** me ha quedado por hacer" (asunto o problema por resolver) pero que no necesariamente incluye terceras partes.

A veces el sentido puede ser casi literal: la asignatura que no aprobamos en su día y a la que tendremos que enfrentarnos en futuras convocatorias.

> El inglés es para mi, a mis 40 año, una *asignatura pendiente*. Nunca lo aprendí bien en el colegio.
>
> Mi formación es buena en historia medieval pero el período previo siempre ha sido una *asignatura pendiente*.

Otras veces el sentido de la expresión es menos literal y más figurado.

> Conseguir eliminar la corrupción es la *asignatura pendiente* de este gobierno
>
> La tolerancia es todavía la *asignatura pendiente* de nuestra sociedad

**Actualización** según las actualizaciones de la pregunta.

Una traducción adecuada para "cuenta / asunto / asignatura pendiente" puede ser

- Unfinished business
- Unresolved matter
- To have a score to settle

Comment: Genial lo de asignatura pendiente, pero estoy buscando el término en inglés para expresarlo. Perdón por no haberlo hecho explícito, ahora edito la pregunta

Comment: quizás debería postear la pregunta en english.stackexchange ?

Comment: @MatiasAndina, yo postearía primero en la sección meta. No tengo nada claro cuando esas traducciones al inglés son "on/off topic". Parece ser que si eres angloparlante y buscas el significado de algo es on topic pedir una traducción al inglés, pero otras veces preguntas muy similares son marcadas como of topic porque piden traducciones al inglés. También tiene mucho que ver que la propia comunidad modera el foro así que creo que lo mejor sería preguntar en Meta para aclararlo.

Comment: si...el on/off topic es todo un tema...voy a dejarlo así y que lo moderen si hace falta. Paralelamente voy a postearlo en english.stackexchange y ver que pasa. Si todo va bien, tendremos una respuesta a la pregunta  (que para eso sirven estos foros)

Comment: @MatiasAndina, por cierto que [por aquí](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/asignatura-pendiente.1398740/) sugieren "unfinished business or unresolved matter", y [por aquí](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=tener+una+cuenta+pendiente) "to have a score to settle" entre otras para _cuenta pendiente_.

Comment: unfinished business la tenía vista...sólo que suena muy mafia friendly

Comment: Jamás había escuchado asignatura pendiente, para mí, asignatura es sinónimo de materia escolar.

Comment: @Jaime, exacto. Y qué pasa con las asignaturas o materias que todavía no has aprobado? Pues que las tienes que volver a estudiar y examinarte otra vez. Por eso, el tener algo inacabado (un proyecto, algo que aprender, etc.) es una "asignatura pendiente".

Comment: La expresión ["asignatura pendiente" está en el DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3zpTQdm). La duda que me queda es si ya existía antes de [la película de Garci](http://www.filmaffinity.com/es/film595299.html) y este la aprovechó para el título o si fue Garci quien le dio un significado más amplio. ¿No se usa fuera de España?